# How to link a GitHub Actions manual run to a PR

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

For a variety of reasons, I need to manually trigger a GitHub Actions run from a comment on a PR mentioning a bot (I’m using ProBot). I figured out how to start the workflow by setting the start to `on: workflow_dispatch` and calling the API. Where I’m running into an issue is linking the run to the PR. Right now, the action just starts and completes without ever appearing in the checks section of the PR.

I noticed that there is a checks create method on the API, but it seems more geared towards making your own check suite. I could use that to create a check run, manually watching the GitHub Actions process, and appropriately updating the check run, but it seems like overkill. I haven’t seen anything in The API that would allow this to happen. There may be a way to do it from the action itself too, but I haven’t found anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can use `workflow_dispatch` to add/update checks on a PR. This seems to be confirmed by [this response](https://github.community/t/workflow-dispatch-does-not-update-commit-status/125981/2) to a similar question on the community forums.

Checks are only added/updated for the following events:

- pull_request
- pull_request_review
- pull_request_review_comment
- pull_request_target
- push

So your manual operation needs to trigger one of these events to run. There are probably a number of different ways you can do this, depending on your use case. Just as an example, you could call the API to add a label and allow a `pull_request` workflow to execute on that type.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled, opened, synchronize, reopened]
```

The other thing to note is that the API call (or git push) must use a PAT instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN`. This is to [allow further workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#triggering-new-workflows-using-a-personal-access-token) to execute.

Comment: Great suggestion! I ended up using on labeled, then an if statement that only makes that workflow run on a specific label. Then I just add the label in the API and quickly remove it. Still seems a bit roundabout (the API should probably just have this functionality), but works perfectly for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with some workaround. First, you have to identify the PR that invoked your workflow. If you need to use the `workflow_dispatch` trigger event, you can pass this PR number as input parameter. Otherwise, you mentioned you trigger this workflow on a specific comment so you could also use the `issue_comment` event which will give you the PR number as `github.event.issue.pull_request`.

Next, you have to find out the latest commit of this Pull Request. This depends on how your workflow got invoked:

- if you use the `issue_comment` event, you can use the [xt0rted/pull-request-comment-branch](https://github.com/xt0rted/pull-request-comment-branch) action to determine the right branch and commit
- if you use the `workflow_dispatch` event, you can use the [actions/github-script](https://github.com/actions/github-script) action to run some query to get the right commit for a given PR number

Finally, you can use the [myrotvorets/set-commit-status-action](https://github.com/myrotvorets/set-commit-status-action) action to attach the workflow result as check on the latest commit of the PR.

I wrote a blog post that describes this process in some more details: [Trigger GitHub Workflow for Comments on Pull Request](https://dev.to/zirkelc/trigger-github-workflow-for-comment-on-pull-request-45l2)